# Javascript Parse Date Contract_End_Date

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

I have Contract_End_Date 2 version : 2020-1-1 and 2020-1-11
Result will be like: 2020-01-01  or 2020-01-11
What is solution here?

```js
var updates = {};
var removes = {};
let Contract_End_Date = '2020-1-11';

if (typeof Contract_End_Date !== 'undefined' && Contract_End_Date != null) {
  var arr = Contract_End_Date.split(" ");
  if (arr.length == 2) {
    var firstPart = arr[0];
    var dateParts = firstPart.split("-");
    if (dateParts.length == 3) {
      var day = parseInt(dateParts[2]);
      if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
      }
      var month = parseInt(dateParts[1]);
      if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
      }

      var year = dateParts[0];
      updates["Contract_End_Date"] = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }
  }
}
console.log(updates);
```

Comment: If you are expecting *Contract_End_Date* to be a string, then `typeof Contract_End_Date == 'string'` is a far better test that the one in the OP, which allows many types that aren't string for which `Contract_End_Date.split` will throw an error.

Comment: Please supply sample input, actual output and expected output. If the value of *Contract_End_Date* is like "2020-1-1", then your issue is: `if (arr.length == 2)` as the result of the split will be an array of one element, not two, so the *if* block isn't entered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For working with dates in JS, I can just recommend "Moment.js".
It makes your code much more simple and readable.
In your case:

```
let Contract_End_Date = '2020-1-11';
let formattedDate = moment(Contract_End_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(formattedDate);
// 2020-01-11
```

For more information: https://momentjs.com/

EDIT: Since Moment.js won't get updated with the newest features, it may be better to use other libaries like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)

Comment: When running your code, I firstly get a deprecation warning regarding passing unsupported formats without specifying the format. Then I get "Invalid date" in the console. Lastly, moment.js is now considered a "[*legacy project in maintenance mode*](https://momentjs.com/docs/)", it should not be recommended for new projects.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
I fixed the format warning, but I still get no "invalid date" error in the console.
And why shouldn't it be recommended, just because they say that it is completed.
There are so many possibilities thanks to moment.js